# Can't find libpq when installing PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I'm trying to install PostGIS 2.2.1 on Mac OS X 10.8.  I've installed all of the prerequisites for PostGIS and am now running the configure command:

```
./configure CC=/usr/bin/clang CXX=/usr/bin/clang++ "CFLAGS=-arch x86_64 -arch i386" "LDFLAGS=-arch x86_64 -arch i386" "CXXFLAGS=-arch x86_64 -arch i386"
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
configure: error: could not find libpq
```

I have PostgreSQL 9.1.4 installed and I believe I see the libpq libraries which is owned by root:wheel:

```
/usr/local/pgsql/lib/libpq.5.4.dylib
/usr/local/pgsql/lib/libpq.5.dylib
/usr/local/pgsql/lib/libpq.a
/usr/local/pgsql/lib/libpq.dylib
```

I did the following but it didn't help:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/pgsql/lib
```

This too in case PostGIS just needs to know where Postgres is installed:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/pgsql
```

Finally, I ran this command with and without sudo:

```
./configure CC=/usr/bin/clang CXX=/usr/bin/clang++ "CFLAGS=-arch x86_64 -arch i386" "LDFLAGS=-arch x86_64 -arch i386" "CXXFLAGS=-arch x86_64 -arch i386" "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/pgsql/lib"
```

What am I doing wrong?  I found another post here where someone else had the same problem but the solutions noted there didn't work for me.

Thanks!

UPDATE:
I'm looking in the PostGIS config.log file and can at least see why the error is occurring.  I just don't quite understand what to do to prevent it.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/pgsql/lib/libpq.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xcf 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/pgsql/lib/libpq.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_PQserverVersion", referenced from:
      _main in conftest-sxaGdF.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by deleting the postgis directory and re-running the commands without any of the command line arguments (CFLAGS, etc.) shown in my initial question.  I did the following:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
make clean
```

I found the "make clean" command while researching the problem.  This command causes the library to run a bunch of tests that validates the installation.  Today I'll be testing my installation but right now, everything appears to be OK.